# Codeigniter validation prevents bootstrap modal to show. How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigniter and have some validation in controller side given below:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_name', 'Customer name', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address', 'trim|required');
```

I have a bootstrap form that create customer and a button that popups modal to add additional info about customer.

```
<form role="form" action="<?php base_url('customers/create') ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="box-body">
                <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                   <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="customer_name">Customer</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer_name" name="customer_name" placeholder="Enter Customer Name" autocomplete="off"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="contacts">Customer Contacts</label>
                       <div><button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addModal">Add Value</button></div>


                    </div>    
    ...
    ...
     <div class="box-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url('customers/') ?>" class="btn btn-warning">Back</a>
                  </div>
                </form>
```

Modal is here :

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="addModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add Attribute Value</h4>
      </div>

      <form role="form" action="<?php echo base_url('customers/createValue') ?>" method="post" id="createForm">

        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="brand_name">Attribute Value</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="attribute_value_name" name="attribute_value_name" placeholder="Enter attribute value" autocomplete="off">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <input type="hidden" name="attribute_parent_id" id="attribute_parent_id" value="3">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>

      </form>


    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

When i click modal button,modal form is showing but close immediately. and validation warnings showing in main customer form. Modal button triggers main form validations.

btw when i use modal button outside form tags, it works without any problem.But i want to use modal button inside form. 
How can i fix it?

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Just change your modal calling `button` to an `anchor`*

Replace this

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addModal">Add Value</button>
```

with this

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addModal">Add Value</a>
```

Your whole form should be like this ;

```
<form role="form" action="<?php base_url('customers/create') ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="box-body">
        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
           <div class="form-group">
              <label for="customer_name">Customer</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer_name" name="customer_name" placeholder="Enter Customer Name" autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="contacts">Customer Contacts</label>
               <div>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addModal">Add Value</a></div>
            </div>    
    <div class="box-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url('customers/') ?>" class="btn btn-warning">Back</a>
    </div>
</form>
```